# MySql After Update Trigger execution order

Tags: mysql, node.js, rest, triggers

I am calling an API of my Nodejs app to update a record in my MySQL database.

I defined an "After Update trigger" on it. the trigger calls a post restful API using sys_exec,to pass the updated record's ID to another API. Then, the other API fetch the record and based on the updated values, will insert a new record in the other table of the same database.

But what actually happens is: first the second API insert new record based on the old values of the record and then the old value update new value.

As far as I know, "after update trigger" guarantees to start executing trigger after updating current record.
any suggestion or help, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The after update trigger runs after the record is updated, but **before** the committing of the transaction.

By calling another api from the trigger, the 2nd insert is most likely runs in a different transaction. Unless you change the [isolation level](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html) to `read uncommitted`, the 2nd transaction can only read the committed, therefore unchanged values of the record.

I would do the 2nd insertion from the trigger, not from another api because the trigger can obviously see the updated values. The 2nd api can still take care of whatever else it is doing at the moment.

I would not recommend changing the isolation level to `read uncommitted` - unless you really know what you are doing. It can have unintended side effects.

Comment: Thanks, Shadow. I would rather pass json file to the API. But I have to encrypt json before sending. if I am correct?